# Searching for selected values in Twig and PHP

Tags: php, twig

I have this array in php:

```
Array
(
    [pageHeader] => Array
        (

            [pageValue] => Array
                (


                    [attractionsArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tourist_attractions_id] => 4
                                    [enable] => 1
                                    [name_pl] => atrackja 2
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [tourist_attractions_id] => 1
                                    [enable] => 1
                                    [name_pl] => nazwa pl1
                                )

                        )

                    [selectedAttractionsArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [related_id] => 4
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

and my twig file:

```
{% for attractions in pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.attractionsArray %}
   <fieldset class="checkboxsas">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ attractions.tourist_attractions_id }}" {% if attractions.tourist_attractions_id in selectedAttractionsArray %} checked {% endif %}> {{ attractions.name_pl }}
                                            </label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    {% endfor %}
```

I would like to check the checkbox as checked for records that:
attractionsArray.tourist_attractions_id == selectedAttractionsArray.related_id

How to do it?

**UPDATED**
My actual array php:

```
[attractionsArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tourist_attractions_id] => 4
                                    [enable] => 1
                                    [name_pl] => atrackja 2
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [tourist_attractions_id] => 1
                                    [enable] => 1
                                    [name_pl] => nazwa pl1
                                )

                        )

                    [selectedAttractionsArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [related_id] => 4
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [related_id] => 1
                                )

                        )
```

I have 2 values in selectedAttractionsArray and 2 in attractionsArray.
attractionsArray - this array has all available attractions in the database

selectedAttractionsArray - this array has only favorite items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to alter your PHP array just before passing it to the View, for example if your array variable was called `$data`:

```
$data['pageHeader']['pageValue']['selectedAttractionsArray'] = array_map('current', $data['pageHeader']['pageValue']['selectedAttractionsArray']);
```

You may check [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) functions documentation to understand the code a little more.

Also make this little change to the twig:

```
{% if attractions.tourist_attractions_id in pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.selectedAttractionsArray %} checked {% endif %}
```

Comment: Did not work. I have 2 records selected. Your code only marks/checked one (first) :(

Comment: Hi, could you update the PHP code to reflect that more than a record is selected in the array?

Comment: Updated the answer too. See if it fits.